Is a Convergent Series of Non-Negative Polynomials Necessarily Continuous?
This may be a silly question, but I was wondering if the following result must hold. Supose that $(p_n)_{n\geq0}\subseteq\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a sequence of polynomials such that $\forall n\geq0,x\in[0,1]:p_n(x)\geq0$. Then, is the following conditional statement true?
$$\boxed{\forall x\in(0,1):\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n(x)<\infty\Rightarrow x\mapsto \sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n(x)\text{ continous as a function $(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$}}$$
This is the case for polynomials of the form $p_n(x)=a_n x^n$. But how about in general? Is it still true? I don't really know since we have absolute convergence but that doesn't really help (I think). I've tried applying Weierstrass' M Test on compact subsets of $(0,1)$ to no avail as I don't really know how to bound $\max_{\left[\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon,\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon\right]}|p_n(x)|$ for $0<\epsilon<\frac{1}{2}$. Thanks in advance!

I think one way of showing continuity is that your sequence of continuous polynomials be uniformly convergent.

@IThinkHighlyOfEiligh Yes, that's what I was thinking. I tried Weiestrass M Test to show that it converges uniformly on compact subsets of $(0,1)$ but I don't know how to bound the terms.

The answer is no as essentially (by Weierstrass approximation theorem) it comes down to the assertion that an increasing pointwise limit of uniformly bounded continuous functions is continuous which is not true.
Concretely, let's take $f_n(x)=1-c_n(x+1/2)^n$ when $0 \le x \le 1/2$ and  $f_n(x)=1-c_n$ when $1/2\le x\le 1$ where $c_n$ is a strictly decreasing sequence to $1/2$ say with $c_1$ close enough to $1/2$ st $f_1>0$ on $[0,1]$
Since $f_{n+1}(x)-f_n(x)= c_n(x+1/2)^n(1/2-x)+(c_n-c_{n+1})(x+1/2)^{n+1}$ when $0\le x\le 1/2$ is strictly positive, it has a positive minimum there $d_n \le c_{n+1}-c_n$.
So one can take inductively a polynomial $Q_n$ at $|Q_{n+1}-f_{n+1}|\le \min (d_n/10, d_{n+1}/10, 1/(n+1))$ for $n\ge 1$ while $|Q_1-f_1|$ is small enough so $Q_1>0$ additionally on $[0,1]$ by Weierstrass approximation which implies that $Q_n(x)<Q_{n+1}(x)$ there and by definition $Q_n$ has the same limit as $f_n$ which is $1$ when $0\le x<1/2$ and $1/2$ otherwise.
Taking $P_1=Q_1$ and $P_n=Q_{n+1}-Q_n$ for $n$ at least $2$ we get a sequence of positive polynomials which sum to $1$ and $1/2$ respectively as above.
